# how to find words in a sentence that have even reverse of those words in python

Tags: python

I would like to get find all the words that have reversed words in a same sentence. 
How ever, the code I got finds only first occurrence of the word. 
in my sentence "i am going to eat ma and tae will also go", I should get an output of am( ma is reversed word) and eat( tae is the reversed word). I only get am..how can i modify this code to get all the words that have reversed words in it i.e. both am and eat.

```
input_str='i am going to eat ma and tae will also go'
word=input_str.split()
def isReverseEqual(s1, s2): 

    # If both the strings differ in length 
    if len(s1) != len(s2): 
        return False

    l = len(s1) 

    for i in range(l): 

        # In case of any character mismatch 
        if s1[i] != s2[l-i-1]: 
            return False
    return True
def getWord(str, n): 
    reverse=[]
    # Check every string 
    for i in range(n-1): 

        # Pair with every other string 
        # appearing after the current string 
        for j in range(i+1, n): 

            # If first string is equal to the 
            # reverse of the second string 
            if (isReverseEqual(str[i], str[j])): 
                reverse.append(str[i])
                return reverse 


    # No such string exists 
    return "-1"
print(getWord(word, len(word)))
```

Output:
['am','eat'] is what expected.

Comment: In my opinion this activity technically cannot be done 100% correctly. what happen If you enter word "deal" but you really want word "lead".

Comment: you are expecting  `['am','eat']`  and not `['ma', 'tea']` because `am` and `eat` appears first in the sentence? or it doesn't matter the order of the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
words = input_str.split()

s = set()
result = set()
for w in words:
    r = w[::-1]
    if r in s:
        result.add(r)
    else:
        s.add(w)

list(result)
```

output:

```
['am', 'eat']
```

this is O(n) time complexity solution, so you have to get first the words  and iterate through them, each time you have a new word you are adding him to a set, if the reverse is already in the set you are adding the reverse to the result

Answer (score 1):

just change the indent of line "return reverse" :

```
input_str='i am going to eat ma and tae will also go'
word=input_str.split()
def isReverseEqual(s1, s2):

    # If both the strings differ in length
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False

    l = len(s1)

    for i in range(l):

        # In case of any character mismatch
        if s1[i] != s2[l-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
def getWord(str, n):
    reverse=[]
    # Check every string
    for i in range(n-1):

        # Pair with every other string
        # appearing after the current string
        for j in range(i+1, n):

            # If first string is equal to the
            # reverse of the second string
            if (isReverseEqual(str[i], str[j])):
                reverse.append(str[i])
    if reverse:
        return reverse
    else:    # No such string exists
        return "-1"
print(getWord(word, len(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str= 'i am going to eat ma and tae will also go'
words_list = input_str.split()
new_words_list = [word[::-1] for word in words_list]

data = []
for i in words_list:
    if len(i) > 1 and i in new_words_list:
        data.append(i)
```

**Output:**

```
['am', 'eat', 'ma', 'tae']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is overcomplicated. For example, function  `isReverseEqual` can be written in one line:

```
def isReverseEqual(s1, s2):
    return s1==s2[::-1]
```

Let's simplify it. First, treat your sentence as a set, not a list, because set lookups are more efficient:

```
words = set(input_str.split())
```

Next, select the words from the set/list if their reversed copy is also in the set/list *and* they are alphabetically smaller than the reversed copy (to avoid duplicates):

```
[w for w in words if w[::-1] in words and w < w[::-1]]
#['am', 'eat']
```

This solution works for lists, too.